Color scheme changes in LyX don't get applied
I'm following https://wiki.lyx.org/Tips/ColorSchemes and copying the settings into the preferences file as explained. However, when I open LyX, the changes are not applied. I'm trying to change the current color scheme because I got a new computer that uses dark mode (and I like it!) but it automatically made LyX dark mode too, and it looks a bit weird in math mode.
Does anyone know if there's a setting for LyX to recognize the preferences file? Or to override the dark mode of the computer? I really don't want to change all the colors manually.
My computer is an Asus Zenbook Duo running Windows 11.
EDIT: More info
To give a bit more information, it seems that LyX doesn't register changes on the preference file at all. Checking or Unchecking the "use system colors" doesn't change anything. However, it changes immediately as I change Windows from light to dark mode. It does change as I change colors manually from the looks menu, but it's a bit glitchy and sometimes I need to change a color multiple times for it to be recognized.

No idea of Windows, but have you noted that the link you posted mentions "uncheck  Use system colors"?  Change the background manually in the same menu (Tools → Preferences → look & Feel → Colors ), push Apply,  and if do not work, try with that check box.

The box is unchecked but still as I change Windows' mode from light to dark LyX changes as well.

I found a half solution for now. If I run LyX in compatibility mode for Windows 8, it doesn't recognize dark mode and the app starts up in the usual light palet, even if the rest of Windows is in dark mode, which is everything I wanted!

The wiki page is a bit outdated. From version 2.4.0 \set_color has three arguments, the name of the object, the color in light mode and the third is the color in dark mode.
So if you don't like the colors in dark mode you can change them, but using wrong syntax will lead to odd results (note that if you run LyX from the terminal and the preferences file has wrong syntax you get warnings).
If you don't want to edit the preferences from the wiki to the new syntax manually, you can use the prefs2prefs script that is shipped with LyX to update the preferences file. Just make sure the format is older than 35.
